# How to check existing triggers on google appscript project?

Tags: google-apps-script

How to check existing triggers on google appscript project?

Eg. I have code like...

```js
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
ScriptApp.newTrigger('onFormSubmit').forSpreadsheet(ss).onFormSubmit().create();

function onFormSubmit(e) {
    do stuff
}
```

Running this code multiple times generates a new trigger each time.
Is there a way to check existing triggers for a project to see if my onFormSubmit function is already linked to the onFormSubmit() event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always call a function  like this before creating another installable trigger:

```
function isTrigger(funcName){
  var r=false;
  if(funcName){
    var allTriggers=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    for (let i=0;i<allTriggers.length;i++){
      if(funcName==allTriggers[i].getHandlerFunction()){
        r=true;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return r;
}
```

As shown here:

```
function createOnEditTriggerForSpreadsheet() {
  const ssid=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId();
  const resp=SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Create On Edit Trigger", "Enter Function Name", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  if(resp.getSelectedButton()==SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.OK) {
    let funcname=resp.getResponseText();
    if(!isTrigger(funcname)) {
      ScriptApp.newTrigger(funcname).forSpreadsheet(ssid).onEdit().create();
    }   
  }
}
```

Comment: When looking at the "Current Project's Triggers" page, I can see an onSubmit trigger, but when adding `console.log(allTriggers)` to the code, all I see in the logs is `[{}]`. Am I missing something here?

Comment: In this case, I think that the object of Class Trigger is tried to see at the log. For example, this can be seen with `Logger.log`. In this case, `Logger.log(allTriggers)` returns `[Trigger]`. This means the Class object of Trigger. When `console.log` is used, the contents of the Class object cannot be seen. So such output is seen. If you want to check the contents, please use the methods for Class Trigger. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getProjectTriggers())

Comment: Thank you. I think that your posted answer for OP's question resolve OP's issue. I think the upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Check all your existing projects triggers

```
var projectTriggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();   //returns a array
for (var i=0; i<projectTriggers.length; i++){
 console.log("Your project Trigger handler functions "+projectTriggers[i].getHandlerFunction())
}
```

Hope I could helped you